# Extracting coefficients in a table

Tags: list-manipulation, output

How can I extract the coefficients in `tab1` and have them written in a table?

[image]
In the case above, the coefficients are the numbers multiplying `\Psi`, i. e., {0,2,3}. As one can see, I tried `Cases` but it doesn't write the zero term.

Comment: Have you seen `Coefficient[]` already?

Comment: It worked, I didn't know this function, thanks.

Comment: I would recommend answering your own question if you were able to find how to solve your problem with that function. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was pointed out in the comments, using `Coefficient[]` one can achieve the desired table as in the code below
[image]

Comment: Next time, please include code as text that can be copied and pasted, instead of a screenshot (unless you need to show something related to graphics or output formats).